# Shopify Liquid variant label background image

Tags: image, shopify, liquid, variant

I have a variant option named "Trim" and it has values Brass, Bronze, Chrome, and Nickel. For each of these labels, I want to have a dynamic background image. Please see the image below.

I want to have background image on Trim option like this

[image: I want to have background image on Trim option like this]

So far, to achieve this, I have created a metafield named "trim_variant_bg" that takes a list of images and have written the following code.

```html
{%- if option.name == "Trim"  -%}
           <label 
            style = "background-image:url(
              {% for var_img in product.metafields.custom.trim_variant_bg.value %}
                {{ var_img | img_url:"master" }}
                {% endfor %}
            )">
 
            </label>
 {% endif %}
```

However, the code is not working. How can I achieve the desired output? Please help.

Comment: adding meta to product or varaint?

Comment: @Onkar sir did we need to add for loop to display meta fields?

Comment: it depends upon meta fields added to the product or variant. if added to variant then need to loop and get the variant meta fields instead of the product.

Comment: Take this as reference if variant meta data is added. https://www.identixweb.com/an-ultimate-guide-to-shopify-variant-metafields-for-your-store/

Answer (score 0):

If you structure your metafields like this

```
{"Bronze" : "your_url", "Gold" : ...}
```

You can just write

```
           <label 
            style = 'background-image:url("{{product.metafields.custom.trim_variant_bg[option.value] | img_url: 'master'}}")'>
 
            </label>
```

Be careful that you're using `img_url` so your URL in the metafields should take that into consideration. Otherwise you can save the final URL and not use any filter.